# What can we say about these two entire functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $g$ and $h$ be two entire functions such that $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\frac{|g(z)|}{|z|^5} = 0$ and $|h(z)|\le |z|^4$. What can we say about $g$ and $h$?

I got to both of them being polynomials of at most degree 4. I'll give you my reasoning:

> Since $g$ is entire, we can write it as $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$, so
> \begin{equation}
> 0 = \lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{|g(z)|}{|z|^5} = \lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{|a_0| + |a_1||z| + |a_2||z|^2 + \cdots}{|z|^5}
> \end{equation}
> But this can only happen if $|a_n| = 0$ for $n\ge5$ (and then $a_n = 0$ for $n\ge5$). Hence, $g(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2+a_3z^3+a_4z^4$, with $a_i\in\Bbb C$ for $i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

> Since $h$ is entire, we can write it as $h(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$, with $b_n = \int_{|z|=R}\frac{h(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$^with $R>0$. Then,
> \begin{equation}
> |b_n|\le \frac1{2\pi}2\pi R \frac{R^4}{R^{n+1}} = R^{4-n}\text{ for }n\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}
> \end{equation}
> If $n>4$, $|b_n|\le \lim_{R\to\infty}R^{4-n} = 0$, so $b_n = 0$ for $n\ge 5$. Hence, $h(z) = b_0 + b_1z + b_2z^2+b_3z^3+b_4z^4$, with $b_i\in\Bbb C$ for $i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Is this alright, or am I mistaken?

Comment: If $|h(z)|\leq |z|^4$ for all $z$, then $|h(z)|/|z|^5\to 0$ as $z\to\infty$. So it would suffice to prove the first case (assuming it is true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote about the function $g$ is not correct. Why would it follow from what you wrote that $a_n=0$ when $n\geqslant5$. For instance, if you consider the sine function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, you also have $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x^5}=0$, but it is not true that the coefficients of its Taylor series centered at $0$ are all equal to $0$ when $n>5$.

You can use that fact that $|a_n|\leqslant\frac{\sup_{|z|=r}|f(z)|}{r^n}$ to prove that $n\geqslant5\implies|a_n|=0$.

What you wrote about $h$ looks fine.

Comment: In fact more can be said about $h$: It is necessarily of the form $h(z) = b_4 z^4$ with some $|b_4 | \le 1$.

Comment: So basically something similar to what I did with $h$. Got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MartinR could the same be said about $g$? Or only $h$ verifies that stronger restriction?

Comment: @GreekCorpse: No, the functions satisfying the first condition are exactly the polynomials of degree at most 4.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what José said: It is true that $h$ must be a polynomial of degree at most four, but more can be said.

The function $h(z)/z^4$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, and the holomorphic extension to $\Bbb C$ is bounded. It follows from Liouville's theorem that $h(z)/z^4$ is constant, i.e.
$$
 h(z) = b_4 z^4
$$
for some constant $b_4$ of modulus at most one.

Comment: I wished we could put various "checks" on this question. Thank you so much for this answer as well!